# Can you make Java enums over Classes?

Tags: java, enums

I am not a Java programmer, but I need to write some Java code, and I have been reading about Java enums, that Java enum class is a special type of class which were introduced in Java 5 to replace int constants. My question is, since there are two types one primitive, `int` and the other `Integer` which is a class, is it possible to create enums out of classes?
Can I have the following for instance?

```java
enum ClassEnum {
 Integer,
 Double,
 MyClass
}
```

The reason I want to do it is because I have 3-4 classes that I need to `switch` on, a dispatch certain methods based on what class I get in my `switch`. All `N` classes that I will be switching over have their own structure, and as a result needs to be handled differently based on what type they are. They are all part of one common abstract class though.

Comment: Why for? Could you give more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: Syntactically speaking, your enum is valid. The real question is: what are you trying to achieve? How would you use this enum? *That* may or may not be possible

Comment: You can create such an enum, but it wouldn't do what - I guess - you think it does. Your question sounds like an XY-problem. What are you trying to achieve here? Enum values are basically instances of (sub-classes of) the enum type, so they wouldn't be a `java.lang.Integer`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys I am updating my question on why I want to do it

Comment: I assume you could have a variable of type class in there, and create your Enums like: INTEGER(java.lang.Integer), but I don't see why

Comment: Maybe you should be looking at [pattern matching switch](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/420) instead, which is in second preview in Java 18. Or use [pattern matching of instanceof](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394) (finalized in Java 16). However, I still find your use case unclear.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel are you talking about this : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html

Comment: Basically yes, but your link is for Java 14, when it was still in preview. Pattern matching of instanceof was finalized in Java 16.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well pattern matching with instanceof seems to achieve my end goal here, but all I wanted to know is if `enums` supported composite data types like classes as I couldn't find any information on if they did. I don't know what I don't know about enums

Comment: @purple_turtle enums *are* classes, and the values are singleton instances of sub-classes of the enum type, e.g. see [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) or [A Guide to Java Enums](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-enums)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you explain this statement: "Note: All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Because a class can only extend one parent (see Declaring Classes), the Java language does not support multiple inheritance of state (see Multiple Inheritance of State, Implementation, and Type), and `therefore an enum cannot extend anything else.`". It seems like when they say enum cannot extend anything, I cannot have myClass extend the enum type. So I even though I can have an instance of myClass on an enum, myClass cannot inherit from enum is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243275/discussion-between-purple-turtle-and-mark-rotteveel).

Comment: no, your MyClass already "implicitly extends java.lang.Enum", it says it right there, in the first sentence you posted

Comment: Okay I see now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest version of the Java, you have lot of options with Sealed Classes and Pattern Matching capability.

Following is one more option that might work in your context. But this approach not recommended.

```
public enum ClassType {
  NONE(None.class), // Could not determine.
  INTEGER(Integer.class),
  CHAR(Character.class),
  LONG(Long.class),
  FLOAT(Float.class),
  DOUBLE(Double.class),
  EMPLOYEE(Employee.class),
  ETC(Etc.class);

  private Class aClass;

  private ClassType(Class aClass) {
    this.aClass = aClass;
  }

  public static ClassType getClassTypeByClass(Class aClass) {
   return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(entry -> entry.aClass.equals(aClass)).findFirst().orElse(NONE);
  }
}

class Employee {}
class Etc {}
class None {}
```

Following sample code for validating:

```
ublic class ClassTypeMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    determineType(ClassType.getClassTypeByClass(Integer.class));
    determineType(ClassType.getClassTypeByClass(Etc.class));
    determineType(ClassType.getClassTypeByClass(String.class));
    determineType(ClassType.getClassTypeByClass(Employee.class));
  }

  private static void determineType(ClassType classType) {
    switch(classType) {
      case ETC: System.out.println(" I am ETC");
        break;
      case INTEGER: System.out.println(" I am INT");
        break;
      case NONE: System.out.println(" Could not determine type");
        break;
      default: System.out.println(" Something else ");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the description of your problem, you might be looking for the [Command pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm). As you mentioned that all classes have a common abstract class, you can add an abstract method (e.g. `execute()`) in this class and have different implementations in each subclass. Then you won't need to use any switch, just call the `execute()` method and the specific logic will be executed according to the subclass. Please check the reference I added here, they explain very well with an example.